# Can't remove phpmyadmin because of file lock

Tags: unix, debian, phpmyadmin

I interrupt my remote-session during the installation of myphpadmin. Now I want to remove and reinstall it. Now suddenly when I type in `sudo apt-get remove phpmyadmin` the following error message occur:

```
 Unterprozess installiertes pre-removal-Skript gab den Fehlerwert 1 zurÃ¼ck
configured to not write apport reports
                                      debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/deb                             conf/config.dat is locked by another process: Die Ressource ist zur Zeit nicht v                             erfÃ¼gbar
dpkg: Fehler beim AufrÃ¤umen:
 Unterprozess installiertes post-installation-Skript gab den Fehlerwert 1 zurÃ¼c                             k
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
 phpmyadmin
```

The text is german

Comment: This might sound stupid (sorry if it does!) but have you restarted the machine since the failure? It should stop any processes that might have a file lock and let you remove it

Comment: @chunkyb2002: Yeah, restarting Debian is usually a stupid suggestion... although it _would_ work in this case :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like dpkg is still running.  Try killing it:

```
killall dpkg
```

Then re-run your removal command.